# Get text between 2 strings (First & last occurrences)

Tags: javascript, regex

I need a function that gets the text between 2 strings. There are plenty of regex examples such as `cow ([\s\S]*?) milk` but consider the following string where we want to get all the text between `{%` and `%}`:

```
{%The anxious brown fox ripped the%} face off the frog%}
```

Desired result string:

```
The anxious brown fox ripped the%}face off the frog
```

The purpose of this is to create a simple substring specifier that won't be fooled by user input trying to trick it.

Comment: `{%` is the start string. `%}` is the end string. I want everything in between, including if someone puts more `{%` or `%}` in between.

Comment: That was a typo. Corrected it.

Answer (score 1):

Match `{%`, then greedily match anything, then match `%}`, so that the last occurrence of `%}` gets matched, and capture everything inside the `%`s so you can extract it from the match array:

```js
const str = '{%The anxious brown fox ripped the%} face off the frog%}';
const result = str.match(/{%([\s\S]*)%}/)[1];
console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
let mystring = '{%The anxious brown fox ripped the%} face off the frog%}'
mystring.substring(mystring.indexOf('{%')+2,mystring.lastIndexOf('%}'))
```

Comment: Your answer will  be far more effective if you output the result with a call to `console.log`. Strictly speaking, the OP was looking for a regex solution. But does the OP really care?